# How can I check that the next input is an integer while checking if it's > and < at the same time in Java?

Tags: java

There's two things I'm needing help with. Loop issue 1) I have to initialize this variable outside of the loop, which makes the loop fail if the user inputs a string. Is there a way around that? Basically, if I set N to anything then the do-while loop just immediately reads it after getting out of the

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Calculates sum between given number
 */

public class PrintSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int N = 0;
        String word;

        boolean okay;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number from 1-100: ");
        do {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                N = scan.nextInt();
            } else {
                okay = false;
                word = scan.next();
                System.err.print(word + " is an invalid input. Try again. ");
            }
            if (N > 100 || N < 1) {
                okay = false;
                System.err.print("Invalid Input. Try again. ");
            } else { 
                okay = true;
            }
        } while (!okay);
        loop(N, 0);
    }

    public static void loop(int P, int total) {
        while (P >= 1) {
            total = total + P;
            P--;
        }

        System.out.println(total);

    }
}
```

If not, then the issue becomes, how do I solve this? I thing that I need to be able to say

```
if (scan.hasNextInt() || ??? > 100 || ??? < 1) {
                okay = false;
                word = scan.next();
                System.err.print(word + " is an invalid input. Try again. ");
            } else {
                okay = true;
            }
```

What do I put in the ??? to make this work? I think I just don't know enough syntax.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you taking the input? Basically what is ```scan```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this?

```
do {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                N = scan.nextInt();
            } else {
                okay = false;
                word = scan.next();
                System.err.print(word + " is an invalid input. Try again. ");
                continue;
            }
            if (N > 100 || N < 1) {
                okay = false;
                System.err.print("Invalid Input. Try again. ");
                continue;
            } else { 
                okay = true;
            }
        } while (!okay);
```

`break` is used to end the loop as soon as the user enters the invalid character(condition of the else clause), so the loop doesn't fail.

Looking at your edited question, `continue` is what you are looking for if you might want to allow the user to enter another value after entering the invalid value.

Use `break` or `continue` based on requirement. [More](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp) on breaks and continue. 
Your second approach can be solved as follows:

```
if (scan.hasNextInt()){
    N = scan.nextInt();
    if (N > 100 || N < 1) {
        System.err.print("Invalid input. Try again. ");
    }
    //perform some operation with the input
}
else{
    System.err.print("Invalid Input. Try again. ");
}
```

Comment: >You can stack >if >if statements.

Welp I think that solved the issue, thank you!!